# Sanitise unicode pair for filename in javascript?

Tags: javascript, emoji, firefox-addon-webextensions, unicode-string, web-extension

My web-extension fails to initiate file download for filenames having a pair of emojis with invalid filename error, this seems to be some `unicode surrogate pair` issue when multiple emojis are used. Here is the offending filename example:

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com/filestream.xyz"
   download="The New World Order Presentation ‍.pdf"
   target="_blank">Download File</a>
```

As evident from the 'Chrome devtools DOM elements' screenshot below the farmer emoji (https://emojipedia.org/man-farmer/) seem's to be a combination of multiple code-points and is the reason causing the filename to be invalid. When the code is pasted here as above the emoji's are correctly parsed as farmer and flag but when we see it in Dev-tools DOM they are different. **Inspecting the filename shared above in devtools displays the issue.**

[image: The Farmer Emoji]

The code which pushes the download:

```
function notifyExtension(e) {
  var elem = e.currentTarget;
  var fileSaveName = elem.getAttribute("download");
  e.returnValue = false;

  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  var loop = elem.getAttribute("loop");
  if (loop) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      url: elem.getAttribute("href"),
      filename: fileSaveName,
    });
  }
  return false;
}
```

The background code which starts the download using browser api:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
  
  let fname = message.filename
    .trim()
    .replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",<>{}[\]\\/]/gi, "-")
    .replace(/[\\/:*?"<>|]/g, "_")
    .substring(0, 240)
    .replace(/\s+/g, " ");
  chrome.downloads.download({
    url: message.url,
    filename: fname,
    conflictAction: "uniquify",
    saveAs: true,
  });
});
```

The error we get in browser console:

> Unchecked lastError value: Error: filename must not contain illegal
> characters

[image: Error in browser console]

How to sanitise the string to have only valid filenames for such situations in javascript? It seems emojis are not an issue, but multiple emojis are !!!

Comment: Where and how is the error reported?

Comment: Invalid filename Error is reported in Chrome extension Error page. chrome://extensions/?errors=ExtensionUUID_HERE

Comment: @Pointy Did you got my last comment?

Comment: Please talk about that in your post, and show the actual error(s) - [in text, not images](/help/how-to-ask). Also please explain what you consider sanitizing in this context. Stripping emoji entirely? Just removing zero-width characters?

Comment: why aren't use using [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download) api

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans @bogdanoff I am using `download` api. See edited question.

Comment: That still leaves the question of what you consider "sanitizing" to mean. Because changing the string is trivial, just update `fileSaveName` as needed. You can, of course, just strip out all emoji using a regex (by removing anything code point 0x1F600 or higher, as well as the zero width joiner 0x200D).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans We need to strip emoji's only if fails as a filename, i.e. when we encounter a situation like one above having complex emoji's. We would not want to filter out emoji's in 99% of cases which saves fine as a filename.

Comment: In that case you probably want to just check for the zero-width joiner, and if there is on, remove "one or more" of "emoji or zwj" in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Unicode properties class to find emojis in a string

syntax is \p{...}

example

```js
console.log("‍aa".replace(/\p{So}/gu, ""))
```

there are more options to use class \p{...}, you can see them in docs

If single emojis do not cause a failure, but man farmer does cause of the problem is **zero width joiner**. It is an invalind symbol in filenames in chrome. Run a search for U+200D

Resulting regex

```
/\p{So}\u{200D}\p{So}/gu
```

Comment: "It seems emojis are not an issue, but multiple emojis are !!!"

Comment: What did you mean? Two in order?

Comment: if (filename.match(emojiregex).length > 1) you mean this?

Comment: Yes, we need to strip a emoji only if fails as a filename.

Comment: I updated the answer. Multiple emojis do not cause error separately, but man farmer is two emojis glued with zwj.

Comment: @WannabeCoder, I think it is not a good idea to modify filename in code. Just log an error or ask to rewrite filename without illegal characters